# List feature branches missing commits from develop branch

Tags: git, branch

Is there anyway to perform something like `git for-each-ref --not-contains`

I want to show shows only the `feature/` branches that do not contain all the commits from develop (in other words, the `feature/` branches whose tip commits are NOT descendants of the tip of develop commit)

Answer (score 0):

`git branch --contains` lists all the branches that contain the current commit. `git branch` lists all the local branches, and you can use `grep` to show the branches from the second list missing in the first list:

```
git branch --contains | grep -vFf- <(git branch)
```